# Sort cells in alphabetical order in OpenOffice Calc to be equal in columns

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am having a tab with names in each cell. The names are organized in rows. What I need is to sort them alphabetically and have equal cells in each column. The problem is there is not the same amount of filled cells in the row, so the normal function of alphabetical sorting will sort them, but they will not be equal in each column. The other problem is, I don't know, how to sort in rows.

Comment: What if in any of the rows the same name appears two or more times? Add additional columns for this name? Remove duplicate?

Comment: There are no duplicates, so the same name does not appear twice in a row.

Comment: Thus, you need to get the complete list of names, sort it alphabetically and place it on the first row of the results sheet (like as header). Fill in all subsequent cells using a simple formula. When the entire "sorted list" is complete, get rid of the formulas in any convenient way (for example, copy and paste special-values) and move the result to the original sheet. To give more detailed instructions, I must see the sample data.